# Passing command line argument to an application

Tags: perl, command

I would like to execute an application from a Perl script.

The Perl script calls the application with a variable as a parameter, the value of which is a long string with lots of spaces within.

The application interprets these as separate strings but I want all of it as one string.

Here's the code in the Perl script:

```
$command = "Hello world here i come. Hope this works"
```

when the Perl script tries to call the application

```
./a.out $command
```

and within the applicaion I try to access `argv[1]`, I only get the string `Hello`. `argv[2]` contains `world` but I want `argv[1]` to contain the complete string contained in `$command`. How do I do it?

Comment: Add doublequotes around the string and escape any doublequotes within the string.

Answer (score 5):

Use a multiple argument form of exec

```
exec "./a.out", $command
```

In this way the shell doesn't get involved